# How can i use a string from python code in my kivy file

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am working on a project an need to use my username in my kivy code as a title of my MDToolbar.
Can somebody pls help my i dont know how to do it

```
def verify(self, username, password):
    if username != "" and password != "":
        for row in MySqlNames:
            if row[0].strip() == username:
                sql = "SELECT Password from ID191774_6itn1project7.Users where Username = %s "
                mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
                TestPassword = mycursor.fetchall()
                for row3 in TestPassword:
                    if row3[0].strip() == password:
                        dialog = MDDialog(title="Login successful")
                        dialog.open()
                        self.username = username
                        GipApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'main'

                    if row3[0] != password:
                        dialog = MDDialog(title="Passwords is not correct.")
                        dialog.open()
    else:
        dialog = MDDialog(title="Fill in the empty text boxes")
        dialog.open()
```

i need to use the string self.username in my kivy code as the title of my md toobar.

```
NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:    
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDToolbar:
                    title: GipApp.username
                    left_action_items:[["menu",lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                    elevation :12
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .95}
```

i hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 0):

If you make a `StringProperty` named `username` in your `App`, then you can reference it in your `kv` as `app.username`:

```
            MDToolbar:
                title: app.username
```

If you use `Builder.load_...` to load the `kv`, make sure you do it in the `build()` method. Otherwise you may get errors that `app` is not defined or is `None`.

Comment: yes i do it in a builder. load but what am i supposed to do    """class GipApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        self.username = "unknown"
        self.usernameKV = "unknown"
        return screen
"""

Comment: Then , in your `App` do `self.username = "Fred Flintstone"` or whatever name you want.

Comment: i dont understand sorry